Japanese TV show that had a recurring plot device, the seal of the emperor
So, a long time ago at an anime convention (I think it was Otakon 2001 or 2002). A guy showed this parody video, which was supposed to be lampooning a popular TV show. This TV show's main character was apparently a government official in disguise, who would go around doing good, and by the end of the episode, he would resolve whatever conflict he was having by revealing his position by showing the seal of the emperor. I could have sworn the character's name was Mikotoun. 
Anyway, I've always been curious to find out more about this, but I've been unable to find anything about this series (admittedly, this isn't a lot to go on). The parody video itself was clearly made before 1990 - I would venture to say the TV show it was parodying was probably from the 60s or 70s, and was supposed to be set in the Tokugawa period (Edo era). The parody was live action, and I believe the TV show was as well.

Found it! It's Mito Koumon, not Mikotoun, which is why my Google-fu was failing me. 
This allowed me to find the parody video too. (I know the quality sucks, but that's about how I remember it being when I first watched it, so I don't think there's a better copy out there, at least not subtitled.)
